# How memory is allocated for a task in Apache Airflow and how to increase it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, airflow

There is task in Apache airflow platform which pulls the data through pandas data frame with a SQL. The size of data is more than 600k. Below is the code:

```
def stage1_data_extract(**kwargs):
    sql="some sql logic"
    df1 = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

    df1 = df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.duplicated()]

    return df1
```

I have observed that when the Apache airflow task returns the above data frame in task, the Apache airflow hangs and i need to kill all the processes manually to get the server up and running again.

Looks like airflow task is running short of resource/memory for a 600k capacity data-frame returning.

I have few questions:

1. How airflow allocate memory capacity/resources for each task,is it the RAM capacity of server where airflow is running?
2. Is there a way to increase the memory capacity of a particular task by increasing RAM capacity of server or how it can be done?

Suggest if there is way to handle such memory intensive task in airflow or any better way to handle such scenarios.

Also let me know how exactly a task gets its memory allocations in airflow.

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of airflow is to schedule ETL tasks and not to run the tasks directly. But here you are overwhelming the airflow server by loading too much data. These are possible solutions for this:

1. If you are running in your local machine using docker, you can 
   manually increase the container memory depending on your system.
2. Setup the airflow in cluster mode in which the server, scheduler,
   and workers run on different machines assuming you have required resources.